# Check how many times and if exactly one item in list exists in another list

Tags: python, list, set

I have multiple lists which contain lists and I would like to make sure there's exactly one common item for each list. So far what I got is:

```
def func(lst1):
    first = lst1[0]
    for i in lst1:
        if not any(i in lst for i in first):
            return False
        for j in i:
            first.add(j)
    return True
```

which helps determine if there is a common item but not counting it.

Comment: The key thing missing from your post is an example of your input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what your code does exactly but I'll try help.

```
def func(lst):
    common_item_count = []

    for i in lst:
        if not common_item in lst:
            return False
        else:
            common_item_count.append(lst.count(common_item))
    return True
```

Does this work how you want it to?

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely the sort of thing that sets are for. You can find the common elements of a collection of lists by casting them to sets and finding the intersection. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp

I would give a code sample but I cannot understand the code in your question.